# Cakephp 2.4.2 - default layout loading instead of ajax layout

Tags: ajax, cakephp, layout, default

I try to load the `ajax` layout but every time is the default layout which is loading.

```
public function getByZone() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';    
        ...
    }
```

So my combo box contain all of my ***default.ctp*** instead of my "ajax answer"

I've tried many solutions, found on the web but nothing works.

disable layout with `$this->layout = false, $this->render('my_view_name', false), $this->autoRender = false,`

see if i don't have any **beforeRender** in my **AppController**, ...

if you have any solution, well thanks for your help.

Comment: try to use `$this->layout = 'ajax';` in your view file

Comment: does `ajax.ctp` exist?

Comment: I just tried to add $this->layout = 'ajax' at the top of my view file but nothing changed. And yes ajax.ctp exists, it's in View/Layouts/ajax.ctp like the others layouts. @Deekey thanks for your edit.

Comment: Is your layout being set somewhere else? For example, in beforeRender() (either in the controller itself, or maybe the app_controller? If so, that will override whatever you set in your controller as it's executed after the controller logic is executed.

Comment: add $this->autoRender = false; and make sure ajax.ctp exist

Answer (score 1):

add `$this->autoRender = false;`

Answer (score 0):

First try with a regular URL in the browser. That will tell you if it is your ajax call or something in your code. Normally I try to simplify things so I have less things to cause the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had Cakephp 2.0 and upgraded to 2.4 and when I ran across this question, I became pretty certain I had the same problem. I ended up changing

```
$this->render('ajax', 'success');
```

to

```
$this->render('/Layouts/ajax', 'ajax');
```

But that's not all! Further, and maybe just because of some klugy way I was doing things, I changed

```
$this->request->params['url']
```

to

```
$this->request->query
```

i.e. my http parameter bozopants in this url http://myurl.com/controller/action?bozopants=1 is now addressed in the controller as $this->request->query['bozopants']

Of course this is happening in a controller with rather strict Auth restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a redirect on the page, make sure you have access to "getByZone" function, or if it is necessary to log into the APP

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2.5.4 I'm just using the following lines to render only JSON output:

```
   $this->set("data", $myData);
// $this->render(string $view, string $layout);
   $this->render(false, "ajax"); // Not using a view, only using a layout "ajax".
```

In the "ajax" layout, the variable $data will be available as viewVariable.